# Javascript Database Live-Search with 3 Inputfields

Tags: javascript

I am completely new with Javascript.

I've a Database with Zip-Codes that I want to filter with an Javascript Live-Search.

Here my Code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

        /* Get input value on change */

        var inputVal = $(this).val();

        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");

        if(inputVal.length){

            $.get("lookup.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){

                // Display the returned data in browser

                resultDropdown.html(data);

            });

        } else{

            resultDropdown.empty();

        }

    });



    // Set search input value on click of result item

    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){

        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());

        $(this).parent(".result").empty();

    });

});

</script>
```

The 3 fields are one "select-field", one "input-field" with text and one "input-field" with numbers.

How must I change the Js-code to get all 3 searchfields for the live-search?

Comment: Make a separate function to call ajax and run that function on change of any of input.

Comment: And how do i get it done?